# cert-manager Ingress Controller cannot find certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt

I setup kubernetes on digitalocean and I installed cert-manager for setting up ssl with letsencrypt. However, I keep getting the fake certificate. what could I be missing?

```
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: ddddddddd@gmail.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: aegle-tls-certificate
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx'
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tripotn-ingress-nginx
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
  labels:
    app: tripotn
spec:
  rules:
    - host: tripotn.io
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: tripotn-web-production
            servicePort: 80
    - host:  twist.tripotn.io
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: tripotn-twist-production
            servicePort: 80
    - host:  api.tripotn.io
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: tripotn-backend-production
            servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - tripotn.io
    - twist.tripotn.io
    - api.tripotn.io
    secretName: tripotn-tls-certificate
```

I get this error from my ingress controller

6 backend_ssl.go:46] Error obtaining X.509 certificate: unexpected error creating SSL Cert: no certificate PEM data found, make sure certificate content starts with 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE'
I followed the instructions here to set it up:

`https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/`

Comment: Hi, can You check if the certificate You used is not letsencrypt staging certificate? Staging environment returns fake certificate. Also verify if the certificate has correct format matching requirements from [k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls) documentation.

Comment: @PiotrMalec I am sure it is not staging. In fact, I just discovered the certificate for staging is also not been gotten from letsencrypt. It gets stuck in progress.

Comment: Have You managed to fix the issue? Is Your certificate a wildcard cert for `*.tripotn.io`?